# Can I run packages on an external hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd

Can I run packages like metasploit, ngrok, gparted, etc all install from terminal but run or install to external hard drive?

I am running Ubuntu on USB 3.0 but I want all packages installed to an external hard drive. Can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use apt-get or aptitude to install software to non standard location?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18704/can-i-use-apt-get-or-aptitude-to-install-software-to-non-standard-location) or [How to install packages to external drive (and run them)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938144/how-to-install-packages-to-external-drive-and-run-them)

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu's default package download location is /etc/, or to /usr/ locations, and as far as I know, there is no way to change it. However, it is possible to move files, etc. to the other drive and have the service files pull from a newly specified location, ie. on your other drive.
The best option would be to use one drive or the other for your main drive, using one as a primary, and the other as a backup, or shared drive.

Comment: A package will provide multiple files. When you use APT, binary files (the actually executables) get placed in `/usr/bin` (there may be exceptions). Shared libraries and documentation files may go somewhere in `/usr/lib/...` or `/usr/share/...` Files in `/etc` are generally for configuration. There should not be executable files there. Because of the way software requires multiple files and expects them in various different locations, and depends on other software in other locations, it would be really difficult to set this up. See answers on linked proposed dupes